# PhD in physics but freelance software dev. Chance of aus 189?

Tags: australia

My qualifications are in physics, however post PhD I only worked in physics for 6 months before moving into the world of software development.

It is pretty normal in the UK for software developers to come from (and be head hunted from) physics and maths backgrounds. But nevertheless my qualifications are obviously not directly ICT related.

Would I stand any chance in getting a positive assessment from ACS with a recognition of prior learning or otherwise? Or would it be a waste of time?

What about if I nominated my career as "physicist" or "mathematician" instead? I don't work in this field now and outside of education only have six months work experience in it, since I left for software. But would this potentially get me more points for the qualification at least if not the work experience?